# query on net DSA driver for x86 ACPI based systems

Tags: drivers, acpi

It looks like the DSA driver code did not ave support for ACPI x86 systems. Do I need any additional changes in the DSA driver code for working with ACPI based systems ? when I looked the code it uses DT (device tree). I am referring the code linux-5.15/drivers/net/ethernet/micrel/i2c-ksz9897.c.

Regards
Simon